# SQL server Database connection using Perl DBI

Tags: sql-server, perl, cgi

I am trying to connect SQL server database using perl DBI/DBD from my local machine but facing an issue and getting error as : `Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0 at C:\Users\user12345\Desktop\PerlExamples\MyPerlExample2.pl line ...`

Now, I am having remote connection to the Database server and able to successfully connect. Also, I even ran the telnet command with IP address and port of SQL server so telnet was also successful. What I feel that something is going wrong with input parameters I am trying to use here.

Below snapshot illustrates the perl code and database details and here I want to connect database "XYZ" as shown in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d774J.jpg).

Comment: User you connected thru client and service account which Perl is running both are same?

Comment: Yes, they are same. But, I can again cross verify if they are same or not. Any proper steps for verification?

Comment: Looks like your $DSN is setting driver of MySql not the SQL Server, change that to ODBC, I provided below as answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your connection string $DSN points driver to mysql database, change that to MSSQL Server as below:

```
$connectDB = DBI->connect("dbi:ODBC:Driver={SQL Server};Server=ServerIP_or_name;UID=$user;PWD=$password")
```

Comment: I tried to connect using the above code but getting Error `SQL-28000` which happens when the login is not valid and user is not an authenticated user. I tried to find the username whether it exists inside database so I logged into database and then navigated to `Security->logins` and I can see the user exists. Now, Is there any way to find the user credentials because what I think the credentials I am using is not valid.

Comment: It uses SQL Server login, as you said you need to check in Security/Logins in SQL Server for having required access

Comment: Thanks Kannan It was helpful.